# convert PersistValue to Text in Yesod

Tags: haskell, persistence, yesod

I want get the attribute value from Persist Entity; so i have the following code

```
userToText userId = do
    user <- runDB $ get404 userId
    userName user
```

This code doesn't compile, so I wrote those alternative version

```
userToText userId = do
    user <- runDB $ get404 userId
    listToJSON [user]


userToText userId = do
    (_,_,_,_,_,name,_,_) <- runDB $ get404 userId
    show name
```

All generate the same error

```
Handler/Report.hs:105:9:
Couldn't match expected type ‘HandlerT site IO b’
            with actual type ‘Text’
Relevant bindings include
  userToText :: Key PersistValue -> HandlerT site IO b
    (bound at Handler/Report.hs:102:1)
In a stmt of a 'do' block: listToJSON [user]
In the expression:
  do { user <- runDB $ get404 userId;
       listToJSON [user] }
```

thanks for the help

Comment: Your problem seems to be that you expect `userToText something` to be `Text`, whereas if you use runDB it can only be `HandlerT someSite IO Text`.

Comment: I want generate a CSV file from a table, how can get a Text if only have the Id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is in the `Handler` monad, so your function needs to return something of the type `Handler Text` rather than just `Text`:

```
userToText :: UserId -> Handler Text
userToText userId = do
    user <- runDB $ get404 userId
    return $ userName user -- Note the `return` here
```

(This is similar to how functions like `getLine` have type `IO String` rather than `String`).